# Move Product Description Div Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to move the product description div outside of the #container just below my .site-inner .wrap

I have already unregistered the tabs and moved my description with these functions:

```
//Remove all tabs 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
//Add product description back to page after removing tabs
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
    woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 32 );

//Add div around product description
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hooks_open_div', 31);
function hooks_open_div() {
    echo '<div class="product-description-container">';
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hooks_close_div', 33);
function hooks_close_div() {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Here are some screen shots of how the html code currently looks:
[image]

Here is a screen shot of how I want the html code to look:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
William

Answer (score 2):

I was able to clean up my code a little and in the process got some help to solve my problem.

Lets first start by adding the description to the hook 'woocommerce_after_main_content'. Make sure to conditionally run the code only if on single products (cause that hook is within any wc page/archive) and give it a priority of 20. This appended the description to after closing the content and container div.

Cleaning up my code:

Turns out the way I was using hooks to add a div wrap around the description was all wrong. I was informed it would be easyer and cleaner to place them in the function woocommerce_template_product_description().

Here is my new working code:

```
//Remove all tabs
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
//Add product description back to page after removing tabs
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
    if( is_product() ){
        echo '<div class="product-description-container"><div class="wrap">';
        woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```

Thanks, 
William

Comment: If you want the new `product-description-container` to be just below the product summary, you can use the same priority for both hooks (10)